# Compression method for file transfers in Android

Tags: windows, azure, azure-media-services

I am developing an android app, where I require to upload image/video files really quick. What could be the best approach to do the same? I am using windows azure media server.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [Overview and comparison of Azure on demand media encoders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-encode-asset)? It holds a list of all supported formats and codecs. Find the one suitable for your usage scenario.

Comment: Do you want to upload the image/video file through APP or Publish the media through Azure?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I want to upload the file through app.

Answer (score 0):

I researched and went through the entire documentation on Azure yet couldn't find the right solution for the below problems. So, I am elaborating the list of issues and scenarios for your understanding.

Just to add top-up on this issue. Following are the scenarios.

1. We are uploading the video through app. - Need help is optimising the upload transfer rate by using viable compression.

As of now it is taking approximately 1-2 mins to complete the upload.

2. Post uploading the Video we crop the video using FFmpeg codecs in our application on VM and then move the video file to Blob Storage.

Followed by that we use the Azure Media SDK to make an asset to encode the cropped video for adaptive streaming and we also create the Progressive Download file for downloading the video which is cropped and has stiched images with it.

- Cropped and Unstichhed video is played in the app which is of max length 32 seconds.
- This still shows the buffering on the 4G network which is questionable?
- Downloadable file which has images stiched with it comes out with noise in the bottom of the video. (Attached image for ref.) [Ref. Image. Look at the right botton pixelation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1BO6.png)